# Gradle : Multiple configurations for Test tasks

Tags: unit-testing, gradle, junit, integration-testing

I have got two types of tests in my app as follows:

- Unit tests (large number of tests and quick to execute)
- Integration tests (small number of tests but each suite takes considerable time)

My project uses gradle and I want both sets of tests to execute concurrently. As per gradle's [documentation](https://guides.gradle.org/performance/#parallel_test_execution), I can use `maxParallelForks` config to parallelize the execution. However, as gradle distributes tasks to workers statistically (see [here](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/2669)) there is a chance that all my integration tests get allocated to the same worker.

So, what I really want is to have two sets of `test` blocks in my gradle file, e.g.:

```
test {
    include 'org/unit/**'
    exclude 'org/integration/**'
    maxParallelForks = Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors().intdiv(2) ?: 1
}

test {
    include 'org/integration/**'
    exclude 'org/unit/**'
    maxParallelForks = Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors().intdiv(2) ?: 1
}
```

Does gradle support two different test profiles like the above? If yes, can I execute those two in parallel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming you have them all under the same source set: `src/main/java/test`.

I'd suggest creating a separate source set and task specifically for integration tests. See [Configuring integration tests](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#sec:configuring_java_integration_tests).

And since you want to parallelize the execution, then you'll need to create a custom task that submits both your unit and integration test tasks to the Worker API: https://guides.gradle.org/using-the-worker-api/

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Gradle 7.4 the The built-in [JVM Test Suite Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/7.4/userguide/jvm_test_suite_plugin.html) is the way to go:

```
testing {
    suites { 
        test { 
            useJUnitJupiter() 
        }

        integrationTest(JvmTestSuite) { 
            dependencies {
                implementation project
                // other integration-test-specific dependencies
            }

            targets { 
                all {
                    testTask.configure {
                        shouldRunAfter(test)
                        maxParallelForks = Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors().intdiv(2) ?: 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```